# Hibernate OnDeleteAction triggered in the wrong order in complex nested domain model, causing ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cascade, cascading-deletes

I have 4 entities

- Project
- Schema
- Stream
- Subject

Project is the highest level entity. Schemas and Streams reference a Project. Subjects reference a Schema and a Stream. These are all ManyToOne relations.

I want these entities to be deleted when the object it points to is deleted. This is modeled in the entity classes as follows:

The stream class:

```
@Entity
public class Stream {
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false) @ManyToOne @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE) private Project project;
}
```

The schema class:

```
@Entity
public class Schema {
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false) @ManyToOne @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE) private Project project;
}
```

The subject class:

```
@Entity
public class Subject {
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false) @ManyToOne private Schema schema;
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false) @ManyToOne @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE) private Stream stream;
}
```

As you can see a Subject entity does not have a cascade delete action when the attached Schema is deleted. This cascade delete is not allowed according to my requirements because the Stream still relies on it. Only when the Stream is deleted should it be possible to delete the Subject.

This all works fine and helps me preserve database consistency, but it isn't intelligent enough when deleting the top level entity Project. Because of all the cascading deletes, all entity instances should be cleaned nicely. But because I cannot control the order in which these happen, the Schemas are deleted first while still being referenced by a Subject, which throws a org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException with something like

> ERROR: update or delete on table "schema" violates foreign key
>   constraint "fk6umsn41vw5j9epv0t7gm1vcbb" on table "subject"   Detail:
>   Key (id)=(9f85c377-7875-409c-b3d8-41b5745190e7) is still referenced
>   from table "subject".

If the Streams would be deleted first, there wouldn't be any problem.

Is there any way I can set this up? Such as controlling the order of cascade deletion. Preferably without any changes to the domain model. When deleting a project I could just get all the Streams and delete them first, but then I might as well not have these cascading deletes setup.

Comment: Is "This cascade delete is not allowed because the Stream still relies on it." an assumption you make or is this a non-technical requirement?

Comment: @Kirinya this is a requirement, the code is mine and this is just a dependency I have.

Comment: If that is a functional requirement, one might argue that it is not in the responsibility of the mapping layer. In that case, you could check this requirement beforehand and change the mapping to cascade. From a Hibernate viewpoint, imho it does exactly the correct thing for your mapping, I think it'll be hard or impossible to change it.

Comment: @Kirinya I think that’s kinda unrelated, these frameworks are here to help us implement our requirements of whatever form. The requirement is not that strange. Right now it depends on the order of deletion whether it succeeds or not, so being able to control that order is a reasonable feature.